# Splitting a string and storing multiple values into recognizable variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, split

I'm storing multiple values in a string in a database. I need to split the string up when I retrieve it to assign it to different unique variables. I'm doing this in VB, and vb is still a bit new to me.

```
Dim scourceString = "<Var1>Person Name</Var1><Var2>11/11/13</Var2><Var3>Somthing else</Var3>"
```

- The string may not have all the values.
- I'd like to split it up and know which `<var#>` i'm dealing with.

Any suggestions on how to do this welcome.

***Edit:***

I've tried this:

```
Dim sx As String = "<tag1>test</tag1>  <tag2>testa2</tag2> <tag3>test3</tag3>"
Dim sb As String = sx.Split(New [String]() {"<tag2>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1).Split(New [String]() {"</tag2>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0)
```

I can get the values but it's dirty.

Comment: What is your expected result? What have you tried at all?

Comment: well i'd like to be able to iterate through and know which var in the string i am looking at and to retrieve its contents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the data is always going to be formatted with beginning and ending XML tags, like that, all you need to do to make it a well-formed XML document is to add a root element, like this:

```
Public Function ParseData(data As String) As MyData
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse("<Root>" + data + "</Root>")
    Dim values As New MyData()
    values.Var1 = doc.<Root>.<Var1>.Value
    values.Var2 = doc.<Root>.<Var2>.Value
    values.Var3 = doc.<Root>.<Var3>.Value
    Return values
End Function

Public Class MyData
    Public Property Var1 As String
    Public Property Var2 As String
    Public Property Var3 As String
End Class
```

Then you could call the method like this:

```
Dim scourceString As String = "<Var1>Person Name</Var1><Var2>11/11/13</Var2><Var3>Somthing else</Var3>"
Dim values As MyData = ParseData(scourceString)
Console.WriteLine(values.Var1)
Console.WriteLine(values.Var2)
Console.WriteLine(values.Var3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    Dim s As String = "<Var1>Person Name</Var1><Var2>11/11/13</Var2><Var3>Somthing else</Var3>"
    s = "<root>" & s & "</root>"
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(s)
    Dim arr As XElement() = doc.Root.Elements().ToArray()
    For Each item As XElement In arr
        Response.Write(Convert.ToString(item) & "<br>")
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not split the string with `<Var#>` as you don't not what exactly the "#" value is. So what you can do is store the value with a common and `unique` separator like (use `"¥"` or what you want)

```
Dim scourceString = "Person Name¥11/11/13¥Somthing else"
```

Now to split the string try split method like this

```
Dim TestArray() As String = scourceString.Split("¥")
```

you have all the values in the TestArray() and you can access them by index as TestArray(0), TestArray(1) .....

Comment: `You can not split the string with...` what's with `Regex.Split`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's the and so on i.e. there may be more items. Answer updated

Comment: @downvoter what's going wrong with the answer? check the updated answer